# why i am getting a null?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using the provider package for state managment,
i don't know if this issue is because of the provider or i am missing something here, i am thankful for anyone who can spot my error,

so this is my ChangeNotifier class

```
class Db extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool _fetchingData = false;
  User _user;

  User get getCurrentUser{
    return _user;
  }

  set setUser(User user){
    print('db_class.dart 15: Setting the user');
    _user = user;
  }

  void setFetchingData(bool state){
    _fetchingData = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isFetching{
    return _fetchingData;
  }

}
```

focus on this getter please

```
User get getCurrentUser{
    return _user;
  }
```

i should get an instance of this user after it was created bu createUser method on this class

```
class Auth extends Db {

  Future<IdTokenResult> signIn(String email, String password) {...}

  Future<IdTokenResult> signUp(String email, String password) {...}

  Future<void> signOut() {...}

  static bool isTokenExpired(DateTime dateTime) {{...}



  void createUser(IdTokenResult idToken) {
    print('auth.dart 53: creatUser method is called');
    User user;

    switch (idToken.claims['claim']) {
      case 'Admin':
        setUser = Admin(
            uid: idToken.claims['user_id'],
            email: idToken.claims['email'],
            token: idToken.claims['token'],
            claim: ClaimsType.Admin,
            phoneNumber: idToken.claims['phone_number']);
        break;
      case 'ShopOwner':
        setUser = ShopOwner(
            uid: idToken.claims['user_id'],
            email: idToken.claims['email'],
            token: idToken.claims['token'],
            claim: ClaimsType.ShopOwner,
            shopName: idToken.claims['name'],
            phoneNumber: idToken.claims['phone_number'],
            //ToDo: get first name and last
            firstName: 'amjed',
            lastName: 'al anqoodi',
            ownerPhotoUrl: idToken.claims['photoUrl']);

        break;
      default:
        setUser = Customer(
            uid: idToken.claims['user_id'],
            email: idToken.claims['email'],
            token: idToken.claims['token'],
            phoneNumber: idToken.claims['phone_number'],
            userDisplayName: 'test',
            userRealName: 'amjed san',
            userFamilyName: 'al anqoodi',
            country: 'oman',
            city: 'nizwa',
            village: 'marfa daris');
        break;
    }
    print('auth.dart 94: ${getCurrentUser.email}');
//    print('auth.dart 75: ${user.email}');

  }
}
```

The problem is when i call the getter getCurrentUser in the add product page i get a null, why is that ?

```
class AddProductPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AddProductPageState createState() => _AddProductPageState();
}

class _AddProductPageState extends State<AddProductPage> {

  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  String _error;
  TextEditingController productNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {...}

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {...}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var db = Provider.of<Db>(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Shop Owner Page'),
            TextField(
              controller: productNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Product Name'
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: priceController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Product Price'
              ),
            ),
            Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Pick images"),
              onPressed: loadAssets,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: buildGridView(),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Add The Product'),
              onPressed: () async{
                if(db.getCurrentUser == null){
                  print('add_product 103: user is null');
                }else{
                  print('add_product 105: user is not null');
                }
                print('add_product 107: ${db.getCurrentUser.email}');
                print('add_product 108: ${(db.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).shopName}');
//                ShopsManagement shopsManagement = ShopsManagement();
//                await shopsManagement.addProduct(claim: (auth.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).claim, shopName: (auth.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).shopName , productName: productNameController.text, price: double.parse(priceController.text), assets: images);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The Issue is Here when i call onPress method i am getting null on "db.getCurrentUser" which it should not be the case...**

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Add The Product'),
              onPressed: () async{
                if(db.getCurrentUser == null){
                  print('add_product 103: user is null');
                }else{
                  print('add_product 105: user is not null');
                }
                print('add_product 107: ${db.getCurrentUser.email}');
                print('add_product 108: ${(db.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).shopName}');
//                ShopsManagement shopsManagement = ShopsManagement();
//                await shopsManagement.addProduct(claim: (auth.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).claim, shopName: (auth.getCurrentUser as ShopOwner).shopName , productName: productNameController.text, price: double.parse(priceController.text), assets: images);
              },
            ),
```

Comment: where you app clashes?

Comment: @Augusto i am getting null on onPress method from db.getCurrentUser, which it should not be the case...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call notifyListeners after this line `_user = user;` on `setUser` method.

Comment: Did you wrap your widget on a ChangeNotifierProvider?

Comment: yea i have to do that to use the provider